# Calculating time complexity of functions when both contain each other?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

Consider the following C code:

```
int foo(int x)
{
  if(x < 1) return 1;
  else return foo(x-1) + bar(x);
}

int bar(int x)
{
  if(x < 2) return 1;
  else return foo(x-1) + bar(x/2);
}
```

What will be the *time complexity* and *space complexit*y for each of `foo` and `bar` function?

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/68896/755

Answer (score -2):

The way to solve this is to look at what the functions are actually doing. There is no general rule. You just have to switch on your brain.

When you call foo (1000), how many calls foo (999) will be made at least? 
How many calls foo (998) will be made at least?

...

How many calls foo (501) will be made at least? 
How many calls foo (500) will be made at least?

Comment: No, the way to solve this problem of mathematics is to use mathematics. There is a huge body of mathematics around the solution of recurrence relations and your comments do it a massive disservice.

Comment: This is stackoverflow.com. As far as this site is concerned, the "huge body of mathematics" might as well not exist. My answer that you apparently down voted after two years explains how to get the answer without knowledge of mathematics.